# subdomain doesn't recognize PHP sessions

Tags: php, subdomain, session

I have a website with a user database and a login form. This system has worked 100% flawlessly. I have a main site with the name= `www.example.com` and a subdomain called `accounts.example.com`. When a user logs in, he or she logs in on the main site, `www.example.com/login.php`.

To view their profile and make edits, they click a link that takes them to `accounts.example.com/profile.php?user=theirusername`. When the page loads, an edit button is suppose to show if they are viewing their own account. I go about doing this like so, `<?php if($user == $dbusername){
echo"<a href='edit.php'>EDIT</a>";}`. This feature works fine if I go to `www.example.com/Accounts/profile.php?user=theirusername`, but on the subdomain it doesn't work. The `accounts.example.com`points to the same path that `www.example.com/Account/` does.

I have no clue why this is happening and I'm using the standard php SESSIONS. When I look inside the Cookies tab in the Safari Inspector it shows 1 SESSION, `accounts.example.com`.

Is there a way to "carry" a cookie to another sub domain?
Any help would be great!
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to use cookie in both subdomains `www.example.com` and `accounts.example.com`, you need to set it on the root domain `example.com`. You need to change the PHP setting [session.cookie_domain](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain) to `".example.com"`.

1. In php.ini you could have `session.cookie_domain = ".example.com"`
2. .htaccess variant: `php_value session.cookie_domain .example.com`
3. Or inside the PHP scripts: `ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com' );`

This is the preferred order: if you have access to the server configuration, you should do this in `php.ini` of the `VirtualHost`s involved. The third option is the worst, since you have to change it separately on every PHP script.

Comment: I used number 3, and it still gave me this error: Undefined index: user in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Website/Account/profile.php on line 98. Any Idea why? Line 98 `if($user == $dbusername)`